# How do you convert opengl texture back to bitmap in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, textures

I wanted to apply image-filter to my image and used [android HelloEffects sample](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/HelloEffects/src/com/example/android/mediafx/HelloEffects.java)

It converts the image data from bitmap to texture.
After applying the image filter effect, I'd like to get the image back in jpeg format, but don't know how to do that.

Comment: How did this turn out for you? I want to use media effects also but I need to be able save the results to a bitmap also. I started to ask the same question as you but then found this question. Is saving the bitmap back from the GL texture the correct approach?

Answer (score 6):

Check the  saveFrame() method mentioned in http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest_egl14.java.txt

Comment: This! This is much faster than any other method I found on SO.

Answer (score 6):

I did this in one way like ,

1. I converted the texture image into bitmap using glreadpixles() method
2. I then saved the bitmap to the sd card

Texture to bitmap code

```
public static Bitmap SavePixels(int x, int y, int w, int h){
    int b[]=new int[w*(y+h)];
    int bt[]=new int[w*h];
    IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.wrap(b);
    ib.position(0);
    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);

    for(int i=0, k=0; i<h; i++, k++)
    {//remember, that OpenGL bitmap is incompatible with Android bitmap
        //and so, some correction need.
        for(int j=0; j<w; j++)
        {
            int pix=b[i*w+j];
            int pb=(pix>>16)&0xff;
            int pr=(pix<<16)&0x00ff0000;
            int pix1=(pix&0xff00ff00) | pr | pb;
            bt[(h-k-1)*w+j]=pix1;
        }
    }

    Bitmap sb=Bitmap.createBitmap(bt, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    return sb;
}
```

Bitmap to internal storage code,

```
 public  static void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    File myDir=new File("/sdcard/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working good but taking much time than 10fps, Can we do it faster about 20fps?

Comment: I am sorry Rohit, I no longer work on android so I cannot help. Maybe someone else can help.